# Formatting JSON sending by AJAX in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, object

I have a problem with formatting JSON object in Google Chrome browser. I wrote example code:

```
    var sendData = {
      'flag': 1,
      'sort': {
          'imie_nazwisko': 'asc'
      },
      'where': {
          'global_percent': 0,
          'analityk': ["Dariusz Doda", "Arkadiusz Garbarczyk"]
      }
    };
```

Bellow is a screen from browser inspector:

[Data in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0ye3.png)

To be sure if all is correct with ajax methodes I attached it:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/setData',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: sendData,
        success: function (data) {
            done(data.MESSAGE);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

In my opinion, code which is going to server had to be a little bit different. Some advice what is wrong?

Comment: What is the issue you're having? You said nothing more than you made an object and sent it somewhere.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong here. The data that Chrome is showing is the exact same format as your `sendData` object, only displayed using a different convention.

Comment: I would use a plain JavaScript object and then use JSON.stringify to convert it when sending.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(sendData),` too lazy to find the dupe right now

Comment: @BlakeConnally I received wrong data from server. I thought that it is a problem with formatting obejct. But it is true that it is different convention and in this case all have to working good. Problem is in middleware.

Comment: @epascarello it's not resolve on question. Of course after your tip it is other formatted, but not the same like in other project. It turned out that the answer was different in ajax dataType. Im not that lazy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

**Declare your object:**

```
var sendData = {
  flag: 1,
  sort: {
    imie_nazwisko: "asc"
  },
  where: {
    global_percent: 0,
    analityk: ["Dariusz Doda", "Arkadiusz Garbarczyk"]
  }
};
```

**Set in the $.ajax() function:**

```
data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
```

So, you can send JSON Object.

[image]

See this demo:

```js
var sendData = {
  flag: 1,
  sort: {
    imie_nazwisko: "asc"
  },
  where: {
    global_percent: 0,
    analityk: ["Dariusz Doda", "Arkadiusz Garbarczyk"]
  }
};

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post',
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
  contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  success: function(data) {
    done(data.MESSAGE);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```